# Increment a column value over and over if it repeats, otherwise reset to 1

Tags: excel, vba

As you can see in the image, the SKU is separated from the image info by an underscore "_" - so I need to take everything before the underscore and count how many times the SKU repeats. If it stops repeating I reset the counter to 1.

I tried using `COUNTIF` formula but it's not working as expecting `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)`

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong? Expected results are below:

[image]

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,TEXTBEFORE(A2,"_")&"*")`

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("_",A2))&"*")` if you don't have Excel365

Comment: Basically `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)` is looking for FULL matches and none of those match fully.  The two proposed formula will take the first part and try a wildcard, or partial, match.

Comment: Thank you both! Post as answer and I will accept. CLR solution worked because I don't have Excel365.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line we write 1. From the second line the formula starts: =IF(LEFT(A2;FIND("*";A2))<>LEFT(A1;FIND("*";A1));1;B1 +1) with underscore included in the comparison or without it: =IF(LEFT(A2;FIND("*";A2)-1)<>LEFT(A1;FIND("*";A1)-1 );1;B1+1)
Depending on the country the separator ; may be ,

```
=IF(LEFT(A2;FIND("_";A2))<>LEFT(A1;FIND("_";A1));1;B1 +1) 'included "_"

=IF(LEFT(A2;FIND("_";A2)-1)<>LEFT(A1;FIND("_";A1)-1 );1;B1+1) 'excluded "_"
```

[image]